# passing data between sub class members

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns

I have the following classes:

```
class WrapperClass
{
SubClass subA;
SubClass subB;
SubClass subC;
}
```

I would like to transfer data between the three subclasses `subA`,`subB`, and `subC`, and was wondering what is the best way to do it. I'm using Qt, and started using `signals` and `slots`, but reached a dead end since I cannot receive data with it.
I thought of having the sub classes as Singletons, but I might need to instantiate WrapperClass more than once.

What other methods I can take?

Comment: You can expose the necessary interfaces in classes A, B, C and inject the dependencies (e.g. obj of class A keeps ptr to obj of class B - not good for circular deps). You can use in-process communication with different comm patterns (take a look at ZMQ libs). You can use a class that will act as a message broker between  your A, B, C classes. Also you can go for sign-slot connections (but yor class needs to be Q_OBJECT); Depends what you need. Your question as-is is not easily answerable.

Comment: Potential approaches depend on your situation, which is not explained well by your question. From what you've described, one answer could be a member function of the wrapper that passes data around. For example: `void WrapperClass::transfer() { subA.get(subB); }` could transfer data from `subB` to `subA`. Are you looking for something so basic? Also, why is it relevant that `subA`, `subB`, and `subC` are subclasses rather than simply distinct objects?